# File not found exception while reading connection.getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, iis, exception, inputstream

I am sending a request on a server URL but I am getting File not found exception but when I browse this file through a web browser it seems fine.

URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
                connection = getSecureConnection(url);

```
            // Connect to server
            connection.connect();

            // Send parameters to server
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(parseParameters(CoreConstants.ACTION_PREFIX + actionName, parameters));
            writer.flush();

            // Read server's response
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

when I try to getInputStream then it throws error file not found.
It is an .aspx Controller page.

Comment: Make sure that your url is correct and in proper format

Comment: If URL wasn't correct the it should give error while trying to openConnection with URL although URL is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I have found that the problem was at IIS side it has been resolved in .Net 4.0. for previous version go to your web.config and specify **validateRequest==false**

Comment: go to your IIS side web.config

Answer (score 1):

If the request works fine in a browser but not in code, and you've verified that the URL is the same, then the problem probably has something to do with how you are sending your parameters to the server.  Specifically, this part:

`writer.write(parseParameters(CoreConstants.ACTION_PREFIX + actionName, parameters));`

Perhaps there is a bug in the `parseParameters()` function?

But more generally, I would recommend using something a bit higher-level than a raw `URLConnection`.  [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) are both fine choices, particularly since it seems like your request is a fairly simple one.  I've used both to perform similar client/server interaction in a number of apps.  I suggest revising your code to use one of these libraries, and then see if it still produces the error.

Comment: Server is returning response code 411. so i believe that there is an error at IIS server end

Comment: @Aizaz - Have you checked the [HTTP Code 411 Documentation](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E411.html)?  Might be helpful.  It would seem like the server expects the `Content-Length` header to be set on the request.  This is something that a browser automatically does, but a `URLConnection` does not.  So I think if you just set this header (either manually on your `URLConnection`, or by switching to one of the libraries I mentioned which will do this automatically like a browser does) you'll be good.

Comment: Yes dear I have set the Content-Length but still of no use. I don't know what the problem with IIS :( It really pissed me off dude.

Comment: I can not use any 3rd party library, and the most interesting is that I am calling server function with wrong parameters then it returns me ok response :(